# Multiple where clause in sqlite3 in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm struggling with sqlite query since 2 days in Android.

Here is details -

I've two table

1. localeResource
2. Banner table

Table structure is -

LocalResource - id, locale, key, value

Banner        - bannerid, bannername, bannerimage, bannerlink, bannertext, countryid, bannerassociate

My query is like -

Working query -

```
select ban.bannerid,loc.value,ban.bannerimage,ban.bannerlink,ban.bannertext,ban.countryid,ban.bannerassociatedstyle from banner ban left outer join localeResources  loc on  loc.key = ban.bannername and loc.locale='FR';
```

But I wanted query like -

```
select ban.bannerid,loc.value,ban.bannerimage,ban.bannerlink,locs.value,ban.countryid,ban.bannerassociatedstyle from banner ban left outer join localeResources  loc, localeResources  locs on  loc.key = ban.bannername, locs.key = ban.bannertext and loc.locale='FR';
```

When I'm running second query my sqlite is hanging and crashing.

Please let me know what & where i'm missing.

Comment: What is the desired meaning? Must `key` match with both `ban` columns, or with one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong:

This one should work:

```
    select ban.bannerid,loc.value,ban.bannerimage,ban.bannerlink,locs.value,ban.countryid,ban.bannerassociatedstyle 
   from banner ban left outer join localeResources  loc on loc.key = ban.bannername and loc.locale='FR'
   left outer join localeResources  locs on  locs.key = ban.bannertext ;
```

You have the on statement at the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks Jens for your query, but it is showing duplicate value, and show ENG & French from outer side.

Comment: @Rakesh Can you add some sample data please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jens, based on your query, correct query is -

```
select ban.bannerid,loc.value,ban.bannerimage,ban.bannerlink,locs.value,ban.countryid,ban.bannerassociatedstyle from banner ban 
left outer join localeResources  loc on loc.key = ban.bannername and loc.locale='FR' left outer join localeResources  locs on  locs.key = ban.bannertext 
and locs.locale='FR';";
```